# Create a heading with a horizontal bar interrupted by text

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, rules

I'm trying to create a command that creates text to look like the image attached.

Specifically, I want a develop a command, say we call it "CenterTextWithLine", such that I type:
`\CenterTextWithLine{Areas of Expertise}`
And I get the appropriate formatting shown in the attached image.

Currently I type the following:

`\rule{0.325\textwidth}{1pt} Areas of Expertise \rule{0.325\textwidth}{1pt}`

but I have to manually adjust the width of each ruling.

How do I go about creating a command that takes a text string of variable length, and calculates appropriate horizontal rule lengths to put on each side of the text?

[image]

Comment: Is it for a section title or something like that?

Comment: @Bernard yes indeed

Comment: You have powerful tools for that with `titlesec`, if you use a standard class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An almost straightforward modification of [one of my answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/271132/4427)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\scshape}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\betweenrules}

\titlespacing*{\section}
  {0pt}
  {2ex}
  {1ex}

\newcommand{\betweenrules}[1]{%
  \leaders\hrule height \dimexpr 0.5ex+0.2pt\relax depth -\dimexpr 0.5ex-0.2pt\relax\hfill
  \quad
  #1% the title
  \quad
  \leaders\hrule height \dimexpr 0.5ex+0.2pt\relax depth -\dimexpr 0.5ex-0.2pt\relax\hfill
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[3]

\section{Areas of Expertise}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]